# Nuxt js Parent Child route

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js

```
pages -
-----cp.vue (main template for all cp folder)
-----cp (folder)
---------index.vue
---------create(folder)
--------------index.vue
```

When I route to `cp/create/` page I want to see the `cp/` page

cp.vue

```
<template>
My cp text
<nuxt-child />

</template>
```

create.vue

```
<template>
my create vue
</template>
```

The expectation for `cp/create` route is:

```
My cp text
my create vue
```

But the result is:

```
my create vue
```

Comment: What do you see on `cp/` route?

Comment: the cp/ is table of data and the create is a modal, I want the table to seems while the create page opened

Comment: @24sharon - did you find a solution?